# What is "The underlying provider failed on EnlistTransaction" Error in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I am having an application hosted in the IIS. My IIS and SQL were in difference systems.Using a single TransactionScope I am inserting into three different tables using Entity framework. Now I am getting the following error.

"**The underlying provider failed on EnlistTransaction**"

which have the inner exception as

**"Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool."**

this exception have one more inner exception as

**"The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024)"**

These are my following questions,

**Why these exceptions are coming?**

**How exactly the SQL transaction works in the IIS application?**

**For single transaction, why I need to enable Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator?**

Note: This error is not coming frequently, 2 out of 10 times we are getting this issues. Because of this issue, I can't move this code into production.

Comment: Which code throws the exception? We can try to sum up all scenario's that can lead to MSDTC errors but that's not going to be very effective.